# How to read output from cmd.exe using CreateProcess() and CreatePipe()

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

> How to read output from cmd.exe using CreateProcess() and CreatePipe()

I have been trying to create a child process executing `cmd.exe` with a command-line designating `/K dir`. The purpose is to read the output from the command back into the parent process using pipes.

I've already got `CreateProcess()` working, however the step involving pipes are causing me trouble. Using pipes, the new console window is not displaying (like it was before), and the parent process is stuck in the call to `ReadFile()`.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define BUFFSZ 4096

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) 
{
    int result;
    wchar_t aCmd[BUFFSZ] = TEXT("/K dir"); // CMD /?
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

    printf("Starting...\n");

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));

    // Create one-way pipe for child process STDOUT
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa, 0)) {
        printf("CreatePipe() error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    }

    // Ensure read handle to pipe for STDOUT is not inherited
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        printf("SetHandleInformation() error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    }

    // Create one-way pipe for child process STDIN
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &sa, 0)) {
        printf("CreatePipe() error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    }

    // Ensure write handle to pipe for STDIN is not inherited
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        printf("SetHandleInformation() error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    }

    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    // Pipe handles are inherited
    sa.bInheritHandle = true;

    // Creates a child process
    result = CreateProcess(
        TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"),     // Module
        aCmd,                                       // Command-line
        NULL,                                       // Process security attributes
        NULL,                                       // Primary thread security attributes
        true,                                       // Handles are inherited
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,                         // Creation flags
        NULL,                                       // Environment (use parent)
        NULL,                                       // Current directory (use parent)
        &si,                                        // STARTUPINFO pointer
        &pi                                         // PROCESS_INFORMATION pointer
        );

    if (result) {
        printf("Child process has been created...\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Child process could not be created\n");
    }

    bool bStatus;
    CHAR aBuf[BUFFSZ + 1];
    DWORD dwRead;
    DWORD dwWrite;
    // GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)

    while (true) {
        bStatus = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, aBuf, sizeof(aBuf), &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bStatus || dwRead == 0) {
            break;
        }
        aBuf[dwRead] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", aBuf);
    }

        // Wait until child process exits
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        // Close process and thread handles
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        printf("Stopping...\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The code is only half-done, deadlock is inevitable.  ReadFile() will not complete until the process fills its stdout buffer so it needs to be flushed or closes the handle.  The buffer won't be filled since it is only contains the prompt.  And nothing more is added, nor will it close the handle since you are not telling it to do anything.  Not also reading stderr is a bug as well that can cause deadlock, otherwise easy to avoid by telling it to merge stdout and stderr output.  Well, that's why, fixing it isn't very useful.

Comment: How can I do this? Should I create another thread? And how do I flush?

Comment: You can't force it to flush, it is cmd.exe's stdout buffer.  Unless you send "exit\r" to stdin.  The program was designed to be used interactively when you use /k, redirection only works well when you use /c.  Repairing this requires using overlapped I/O so you can read both stderr and stdout asynchronously at the same time and using WaitForMultipleObjects() so you can wait on all three handles.

Comment: Note that `dwRead == 0` is not an error condition. From [`ReadFile` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile): _"If the lpNumberOfBytesRead parameter is zero when ReadFile returns TRUE on a pipe, the other end of the pipe called the WriteFile function with nNumberOfBytesToWrite set to zero."_

Comment: In the example above SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES should be configured before they where used in CreatePipe method.

Answer (score 20):

The subtle way out of your problem is to make sure you close the ends of the pipe you don't need.

Your parent process has four handles:

- two of them are *your* ends of the pipe

  - `g_hChildStd_IN_Wr`
  - `g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd`
- two of them are the *child's* end of the pipe

  - `g_hChildStd_IN_Rd`
  - `g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr`

```
╔══════════════════╗                ╔══════════════════╗
║  Parent Process  ║                ║  Child Process   ║
╠══════════════════╣                ╠══════════════════╣
║                  ║                ║                  ║
║ g_hChildStd_IN_Wr╟───────────────>║g_hChildStd_IN_Rd ║ 
║                  ║                ║                  ║ 
║g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd║<───────────────╢g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr║
║                  ║                ║                  ║
╚══════════════════╝                ╚══════════════════╝
```

Your parent process only needs **one** end of each pipe:

- writable end of the child input pipe: **`g_hChildStd_IN_Wr`**
- readable end of the child output pipe: **`g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd`**

Once you've launched your child process: be sure to close those ends of the pipe you no longer need:

- `CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd)`
- `CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr)`

Leaving:

```
╔══════════════════╗                ╔══════════════════╗
║  Parent Process  ║                ║  Child Process   ║
╠══════════════════╣                ╠══════════════════╣
║                  ║                ║                  ║
║ g_hChildStd_IN_Wr╟───────────────>║                  ║ 
║                  ║                ║                  ║ 
║g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd║<───────────────╢                  ║
║                  ║                ║                  ║
╚══════════════════╝                ╚══════════════════╝
```

Or more fully:

```
STARTUP_INFO si;
PROCESS_INFO pi;
result = CreateProcess(..., ref si, ref pi);

//Bonus chatter: A common bug among a lot of programmers: 
// they don't realize they are required to call CloseHandle 
// on the two handles placed in PROCESS_INFO.
// That's why you should call ShellExecute - it closes them for you.
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

/*
   We've given the console app the writable end of the pipe during CreateProcess; we don't need it anymore.
   We do keep the handle for the *readable* end of the pipe; as we still need to read from it.
   The other reason to close the writable-end handle now is so that there's only one out-standing reference to the writeable end: held by the child process.
   When the child processes closes, it will close the pipe, and 
   your call to ReadFile will fail with error code:
      109 (The pipe has been ended).

   That's how we'll know the console app is done. (no need to wait on process handles with buggy infinite waits)
*/
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = 0;
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);
g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = 0;
```

### Waiting on the Child Process (aka the deadlock waiting to happen)

The common problem with most solutions is that [people try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969730/how-to-read-output-from-cmd-exe-using-createprocess-and-createpipe/35970604#35970604) to wait on a process handle.

- they create event objects
- they try to MsgWait for events to be signaled
- they try to MsgWait for child processes to end

That's wrong. **That's all wrong**.

There are many problems with these ideas; the main one being:

- if you try to wait for the child the terminate
- the child will **never** be able to terminate

If the child is trying to send you output through the pipe, and you're `INFINITE` waiting, you're not emptying your end of the pipe. Eventually the pipe the child is writing to becomes full. When the child tries to write to a pipe that is full, its `WriteFile` call **waits** (*i.e.* Blocks) for the pipe to have some room.

- you're blocked waiting on the child
- the child attempts to write to the pipe
- you're blocked waiting on the child, so you're not reading data out of the pipe
- the pipe becomes full
- the child blocks waiting on you
- both parent and child are blocked waiting on the other
- deadlock

As a result the **child** process will **never** terminate; you've deadlocked everything.

### The Right Approach - let the client do it's thing

The correct solution comes by **simply reading from the pipe**.

- Once the child process terminates,
- it will `CloseHandle` on **its** end of the pipes.
- The next time you try to read from the pipe
- you'll be told the pipe has been closed ([`ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)).
- That's how you know the process is done and you have no more stuff to read.

```
String outputText = "";

//Read will return when the buffer is full, or if the pipe on the other end has been broken
while (ReadFile(stdOutRead, aBuf, Length(aBuf), &bytesRead, null)
   outputText = outputText + Copy(aBuf, 1, bytesRead);

//ReadFile will either tell us that the pipe has closed, or give us an error
DWORD le = GetLastError;

//And finally cleanup
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr);
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd);

if (le != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) //"The pipe has been ended."
   RaiseLastOSError(le);
```

All without a dangerous **MsgWaitForSingleObject** - which is error-prone, difficult to use correctly, and causes the very bug you want to avoid.

### Complete Example

We all know what we are using this for: run a child process, and capture it's console output.

Here is some sample Delphi code:

```
function ExecuteAndCaptureOutput(CommandLine: string): string;
var
    securityAttributes: TSecurityAttributes;
    stdOutRead, stdOutWrite: THandle;
    startupInfo: TStartupInfo;
    pi: TProcessInformation;
    buffer: AnsiString;
    bytesRead: DWORD;
    bRes: Boolean;
    le: DWORD;
begin
    {
        Execute a child process, and capture it's command line output.
    }
    Result := '';

    securityAttributes.nlength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
    securityAttributes.bInheritHandle := True;
    securityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

    if not CreatePipe({var}stdOutRead, {var}stdOutWrite, @securityAttributes, 0) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    try
        // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure.
        startupInfo := Default(TStartupInfo);
        startupInfo.cb := SizeOf(startupInfo);

        // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
        startupInfo.dwFlags := startupInfo.dwFlags or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES; //The hStdInput, hStdOutput, and hStdError handles will be valid.
            startupInfo.hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); //don't forget to make it valid (zero is not valid)
            startupInfo.hStdOutput := stdOutWrite; //give the console app the writable end of the pipe
            startupInfo.hStdError := stdOutWrite; //give the console app the writable end of the pipe

        // We also want the console window to be hidden
        startupInfo.dwFlags := startupInfo.dwFlags or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW; //The nShowWindow member member will be valid.
            startupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE; //default is that the console window is visible

        // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
        pi := Default(TProcessInformation);

        //WARNING: The Unicode version of CreateProcess can modify the contents of CommandLine.
        //Therefore CommandLine cannot point to read-only memory.
        //We can ensure it's not read-only with the RTL function UniqueString
        UniqueString({var}CommandLine);

        bRes := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, True, 0, nil, nil, startupInfo, {var}pi);
        if not bRes then
            RaiseLastOSError;

        //CreateProcess demands that we close these two populated handles when we're done with them. We're done with them.
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        {
            We've given the console app the writable end of the pipe during CreateProcess; we don't need it anymore.
            We do keep the handle for the *readable* end of the pipe; as we still need to read from it.
            The other reason to close the writable-end handle now is so that there's only one out-standing reference to the writeable end: held by the console app.
            When the app closes, it will close the pipe, and ReadFile will return code 109 (The pipe has been ended).
            That's how we'll know the console app is done. (no need to wait on process handles)
        }
        CloseHandle(stdOutWrite);
        stdOutWrite := 0;

        SetLength(buffer, 4096);

        //Read will return when the buffer is full, or if the pipe on the other end has been broken
        while ReadFile(stdOutRead, buffer[1], Length(buffer), {var}bytesRead, nil) do
            Result := Result + string(Copy(buffer, 1, bytesRead));

        //ReadFile will either tell us that the pipe has closed, or give us an error
        le := GetLastError;
        if le <> ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE then //"The pipe has been ended."
            RaiseLastOSError(le);
    finally
        CloseHandle(stdOutRead);
        if stdOutWrite <> 0 then
            CloseHandle(stdOutWrite);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: @SrinivasPaladugu When **ReadFile** immediately returns false (i.e. without waiting, and without returning any data), what error code does **GetLastError** return?

Comment: Thank you! Your thorough answer let me understand and fix my code. Btw do you happen to know a good book that explains such concepts like those deadlocks caused by incorrect usage of pipes ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWolszczak I don't remember how if figured all this out. I had the need to do it, so it was a lot of researching. And when i found the subtle gotcha, i knew i needed to get the correct code out there. So i just looked for a question on StackOverflow asking about getting console output, and used that question as my place to dump the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

Ian Boyd's answer had this gem: **Once you've launched your child process: be sure to close those ends of the pipe you no longer need.**

I've produced another version of the `CreatePipe` + `CreateProcess` solution which, I hope, is more clear:

```
int main()
{
    BOOL ok = TRUE;
    HANDLE hStdInPipeRead = NULL;
    HANDLE hStdInPipeWrite = NULL;
    HANDLE hStdOutPipeRead = NULL;
    HANDLE hStdOutPipeWrite = NULL;

    // Create two pipes.
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE };
    ok = CreatePipe(&hStdInPipeRead, &hStdInPipeWrite, &sa, 0);
    if (ok == FALSE) return -1;
    ok = CreatePipe(&hStdOutPipeRead, &hStdOutPipeWrite, &sa, 0);
    if (ok == FALSE) return -1;

    // Create the process.
    STARTUPINFO si = { };
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdError = hStdOutPipeWrite;
    si.hStdOutput = hStdOutPipeWrite;
    si.hStdInput = hStdInPipeRead;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { };
    LPCWSTR lpApplicationName = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    LPWSTR lpCommandLine = (LPWSTR)L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c dir";
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttribute = NULL;
    BOOL bInheritHandles = TRUE;
    DWORD dwCreationFlags = 0;
    LPVOID lpEnvironment = NULL;
    LPCWSTR lpCurrentDirectory = NULL;
    ok = CreateProcess(
        lpApplicationName,
        lpCommandLine,
        lpProcessAttributes,
        lpThreadAttribute,
        bInheritHandles,
        dwCreationFlags,
        lpEnvironment,
        lpCurrentDirectory,
        &si,
        &pi);
    if (ok == FALSE) return -1;

    // Close pipes we do not need.
    CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeWrite);
    CloseHandle(hStdInPipeRead);

    // The main loop for reading output from the DIR command.
    char buf[1024 + 1] = { };
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    DWORD dwAvail = 0;
    ok = ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, buf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
    while (ok == TRUE)
    {
        buf[dwRead] = '\0';
        OutputDebugStringA(buf);
        puts(buf);
        ok = ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, buf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
    }

    // Clean up and exit.
    CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeRead);
    CloseHandle(hStdInPipeWrite);
    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);
    return dwExitCode;
}
```

Some notes:

- The pipe for StdIn is not really required:

  - This is because the `DIR` command doesn't require user input (but, I left it in the code, since it is a good template for running other commands)
  - everyting to do with `hStdInPipeRead` & `hStdInPipeWrite` can be omitted
  - setting `si.hStdInput` can be omitted
- Replace hardcoded `L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"` with reading the `COMSPEC` environment variable.
- Replace LPWSTR with LPTSTR if we wish to compile for non-UNICODE.
- Replace `cmd.exe /k DIR` with `cmd.exe /c DIR` since when the `DIR` command finishes we don't really want the `cmd.exe` to stick around.

Comment: `lpCommandLine` should not be pointing to a literal string as the CreateProcessW function might modify it.

Answer (score 2):

I too have same scenario. in my case from Lib, need to execute internal exe and read output. The following works without any issues.

```
  void executeCMDInNewProcessAndReadOutput(LPSTR lpCommandLine)
    {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, g_hChildStd_IN_Wr;  //pipe handles
        char buf[1024];           //i/o buffer

        sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

        if (CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &sa, 0))   //create stdin pipe
        {
            if (CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa, 0))  //create stdout pipe
            {

                //set startupinfo for the spawned process
                /*The dwFlags member tells CreateProcess how to make the process.
                STARTF_USESTDHANDLES: validates the hStd* members.
                STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW: validates the wShowWindow member*/
                GetStartupInfo(&si);

                si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
                si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
                //set the new handles for the child process
                si.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
                si.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
                si.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;

                //spawn the child process
                if (CreateProcess(NULL, lpCommandLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                    NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
                {
                    unsigned long bread;   //bytes read
                    unsigned long avail;   //bytes available
                    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

                    for (;;)
                    {
                        PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buf, 1023, &bread, &avail, NULL);
                        //check to see if there is any data to read from stdout
                        if (bread != 0)
                        {
                            if (ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buf, 1023, &bread, NULL))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //clean up all handles
                    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);
                    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
                    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
                    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr);
                }
                else
                {
                    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);
                    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
                    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
                    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);
                CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (taken from a larger program) of a thread that does what you are looking for.  It creates pipes for stdout and stderr for the process it creates then goes into a loop reading those pipes until the program finishes.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
   {
#define EVENT_NAME "Global\\RunnerEvt"

   HANDLE hev;
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES psa;
   InitSAPtr(&psa);
   DWORD waitRc;
   DWORD bytesRead;
   int manual_triggered = 1;

   hev = CreateEvent(&psa, FALSE, FALSE, EVENT_NAME);

   // Create pipes we'll read

      for(;;)
      {

      if (manual_triggered)
         {
         waitRc = WAIT_OBJECT_0;
         manual_triggered = 0;
         }
      else
         {
         waitRc = WaitForSingleObject(hev, 500);
         }

      if (waitRc == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
         {
         `logprint`f(LOG_DBG, "Received command to run process\n");

         CreateChildOutFile();

         stdOutEvt = CreateEvent(&psa, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
         stdOutOvl.hEvent = stdOutEvt;

         stdErrEvt = CreateEvent(&psa, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
         stdErrOvl.hEvent = stdErrEvt;

         gStdOutReadHand =  CreateNamedPipe(STD_OUT_PIPE_NAME, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX + FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE + PIPE_READMODE_BYTE,
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 4096, 4096, 0, &psa);
         if (gStdOutReadHand == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
            log(LOG_DBG, "Error %d on create STDOUT pipe\n", GetLastError());
            }

         gStdErrReadHand =  CreateNamedPipe(STD_ERR_PIPE_NAME, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX + FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE + PIPE_READMODE_BYTE,
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 4096, 4096, 0, &psa);
         if (gStdErrReadHand == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
            log(LOG_DBG, "Error %d on create STDERR pipe\n", GetLastError());
            }

         runProcess();

         log(LOG_DBG, "After runProcess, new PID is %d/%x\n", piProcInfo.dwProcessId, piProcInfo.dwProcessId);

         if (piProcInfo.dwProcessId == 0)
            {
            log(LOG_DBG, "runProcess failed, closing child STDIN/STDERR\n");
            closeChildPipes();

#define FAIL_MSG "Child process failed to start\n"
            writeChildOutFile(FAIL_MSG, strlen(FAIL_MSG) );

            CloseHandle(hChildOut);
            }
         else
            {
            log(LOG_DBG, "Child process created, setting up for redir/restart/termination\n");

            issueRead(gStdOutReadHand, &stdOutOvl, stdOutBuff, &stdOutBytesAvail);
            //log(LOG_DBG, "After read set on STDOUT\n");

            issueRead(gStdErrReadHand, &stdErrOvl, stdErrBuff, &stdErrBytesAvail);
            //log(LOG_DBG, "After read set on STDERR\n");

            HANDLE harr[4];

            for(;;)
               {
               harr[0] = hev;
               harr[1] = piProcInfo.hProcess;
               harr[2] = stdOutEvt;
               harr[3] = stdErrEvt;

               DWORD waitRc2 = WaitForMultipleObjects(4, harr, FALSE, 500);

               #if 0
               if (waitRc2 == -1)
                  {
                  log(LOG_DBG, "Wait error %d\n", GetLastError());
                  Sleep(500);
                  }

               log(LOG_DBG, "waitRc2 %d\n", waitRc2);
               #endif


               if ((waitRc2 - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 0)
                  {
                  log(LOG_DBG, "Woke up because another trigger command was received\n");
                  #define NEW_CMD_MSG "Child process is being terminated because new trigger received\n"

                  writeChildOutFile(NEW_CMD_MSG, strlen(NEW_CMD_MSG));

                  terminateChild();
                  CloseHandle(hChildOut);
                  manual_triggered = 1;
                  break;
                  }
               else if ((waitRc2 - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 1)
                  {
                  //log(LOG_DBG, "Woke up because child has terminated\n");
                  closeChildPipes();
                  #define NORM_MSG "Normal child process termination\n"
                  writeChildOutFile(NORM_MSG, strlen(NORM_MSG));
                  CloseHandle(hChildOut);
                  break;
                  }
               else if ((waitRc2 - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 2)
                  {
                  //log(LOG_DBG, "Woke up because child has stdout\n");
                  if (GetOverlappedResult(gStdOutReadHand, &stdOutOvl, &bytesRead, TRUE))
                     {
                     writeChildOutFile(stdOutBuff, bytesRead);
                     ResetEvent(stdOutEvt);
                     issueRead(gStdOutReadHand, &stdOutOvl, stdOutBuff, &stdOutBytesAvail);
                     }

                  }
               else if ((waitRc2 - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 3)
                  {
                  //log(LOG_DBG, "Woke up because child has stderr\n");

                  if (GetOverlappedResult(gStdErrReadHand, &stdErrOvl, &bytesRead, TRUE))
                     {
                     writeChildOutFile(stdErrBuff, bytesRead);
                     ResetEvent(stdErrEvt);
                     issueRead(gStdErrReadHand, &stdErrOvl, stdErrBuff, &stdErrBytesAvail);
                     }
                  }
               else
                  {
                  if (gShuttingDown)
                     {
                     log(LOG_DBG, "Woke with active child and service is terminating\n");

#define SHUTDOWN_MSG "Child process is being terminated because the service is shutting down\n"

                     writeChildOutFile(SHUTDOWN_MSG, strlen(SHUTDOWN_MSG));
                     terminateChild();
                     CloseHandle(hChildOut);
                     break;
                     }
                  }

               if (gShuttingDown)
                  {
                  break;
                  }

               }
            }
         }
      else if (gShuttingDown)
         {
         break;
         }

      CloseHandle(gStdOutReadHand);
      CloseHandle(gStdErrReadHand);

      }

   return 0;
   }

void writeChildOutFile(char *msg, int len)
   {
   DWORD bytesWritten;
   WriteFile(hChildOut, msg, len, &bytesWritten, 0);
   }


void terminateChild(void)
   {
   if (piProcInfo.dwProcessId != 0)
      {
      TerminateProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess, -1);
      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
      closeChildPipes();
      }
   }

void closeChildPipes(void)
   {
   CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
   CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr);
   }

void runProcess(void)
   {
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

   // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited.
   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

   // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.
   TCHAR szCmdline[]=TEXT("cmd.exe /C C:\\temp\\RunnerService.bat");
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

// Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.

   ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

   g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = CreateFile (STD_OUT_PIPE_NAME,
                FILE_WRITE_DATA,
                0,
                &saAttr,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                NULL);

   if (g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      {
      log(LOG_DBG, "Error creating child proc stdout file %d\n", GetLastError());
      }


   g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr = CreateFile (STD_ERR_PIPE_NAME,
                FILE_WRITE_DATA,
                0,
                &saAttr,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                NULL);

   if (g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      {
      log(LOG_DBG, "Error creating child proc stderr file %d\n", GetLastError());
      }


// Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure.
// This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

   ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
   siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
   siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr;
   siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

// Create the child process.

   bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
      szCmdline,     // command line
      NULL,          // process security attributes
      NULL,          // primary thread security attributes
      TRUE,          // handles are inherited
      0,             // creation flags
      NULL,          // use parent's environment
      NULL,          // use parent's current directory
      &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer
      &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION

   }


void CreateChildOutFile(void)
   {
   SYSTEMTIME st;
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
   char fName[_MAX_PATH];

   InitSAPtr(&sa);

   GetLocalTime(&st);

   sprintf(fName, "C:\\TEMP\\runsvcchild_%02d_%02d_%02d_%04d.out", st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);

   hChildOut = CreateFile(fName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, &sa,  CREATE_ALWAYS,  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
   }

void issueRead(HANDLE hFile, OVERLAPPED *overLapped, char *buf, DWORD *dwRead)
   {
   //log(LOG_DBG, "Start of issueRead, hfile %08x, ovl is %08x\n", hFile, overLapped);
   BOOL brc = ReadFile(hFile, buf, 4096, dwRead, overLapped);
   if (!brc)
      {
      DWORD dwle = GetLastError();
      if (dwle != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
         {
         log(LOG_DBG, "Error %d on ReadFile\n", dwle);
         }
      }
   else
      {
      // log(LOG_DBG, "Read issued\n");
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did everything right. But cmd.exe prints nothing or very little amount of data after start and your ReadFile blocks. If you move your cycle

```
while (true) {
    bStatus = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, aBuf, sizeof(aBuf), &dwRead, NULL);
    if (!bStatus || dwRead == 0) {
        break;
    }
    aBuf[dwRead] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", aBuf);
}
```

into background thread and run other cycle which will read your input and send it to cmd.exe, I think you can see any effect. 
Either you can make read buffer smaller (16 bytes e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

I tried Stephen Quan's answer out and got a segfault. Perhaps someone with more experience might know why that is. At any rate, this should be a more correct example of what he was trying to do:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cwchar>

using std::string;
using std::wstring;
using std::vector;
using std::size_t;

static inline wstring widen(string str) {
  size_t wchar_count = str.size() + 1;
  vector<wchar_t> buf(wchar_count);
  return wstring{ buf.data(), (size_t)MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, buf.data(), (int)wchar_count) };
}

static inline string narrow(wstring wstr) {
  int nbytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), (int)wstr.length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  vector<char> buf(nbytes);
  return string{ buf.data(), (size_t)WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), (int)wstr.length(), buf.data(), nbytes, NULL, NULL) };
}

string evaluate_shell(string command) {
  string output;
  wstring wstr_command = widen(command);
  wchar_t cwstr_command[32768];
  wcsncpy(cwstr_command, wstr_command.c_str(), 32768);
  BOOL ok = TRUE;
  HANDLE hStdInPipeRead = NULL;
  HANDLE hStdInPipeWrite = NULL;
  HANDLE hStdOutPipeRead = NULL;
  HANDLE hStdOutPipeWrite = NULL;
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE };
  ok = CreatePipe(&hStdInPipeRead, &hStdInPipeWrite, &sa, 0);
  if (ok == FALSE) return "";
  ok = CreatePipe(&hStdOutPipeRead, &hStdOutPipeWrite, &sa, 0);
  if (ok == FALSE) return "";
  STARTUPINFOW si = { };
  si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
  si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  si.hStdError = hStdOutPipeWrite;
  si.hStdOutput = hStdOutPipeWrite;
  si.hStdInput = hStdInPipeRead;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { };
  if (CreateProcessW(NULL, cwstr_command, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    while (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 5) == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
      MSG msg;
      if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
      }
    }
    CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeWrite);
    CloseHandle(hStdInPipeRead);
    char buffer[4096] = { };
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    ok = ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, buffer, 4095, &dwRead, NULL);
    while (ok == TRUE) {
      buffer[dwRead] = 0;
      ok = ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, buffer, 4095, &dwRead, NULL);
    }
    CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeRead);
    CloseHandle(hStdInPipeWrite);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    output = narrow(widen(buffer));
    while (output.back() == '\r' || output.back() == '\n')
      output.pop_back();
  }
  return output;
}
```