# CreateProcess cmd.exe read/write pipes deadlock

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

Hello I am trying to make a front end GUI for cmd.exe so I can make it wider but I got stuck.

I try to design an API like this

```
char* Directory = WriteCommand("dir");
printf("- %s\n", Directory);
```

and the output look exactly like it would in a cmd window, except I have it in a string, so it would be

```
DATE TIME FILESIZE FILENAME
etc etc etc
```

and then I can issue

```
char* Up = WriteCommand ("cd ..");
```

and it will give me the above directory listing. So I want a terminal control through using pipes to read and write.

I have tried many things based on this MSDN sample code - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx

But I think this code is only good to issue one command, and read one response, because right after it deadlocks as described here - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110707-00/?p=10223

I see several other questions here, like this one with similar problems - [How to read output from cmd.exe using CreateProcess() and CreatePipe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969730/how-to-read-output-from-cmd-exe-using-createprocess-and-createpipe) but no solutions posted work for me.

So here is my code.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

void CreateChildProcess(void);
void WriteToPipe(char* Arg1);
void ReadFromPipe(void);
void ErrorExit(PTSTR);



int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create the child process. 

    CreateChildProcess();

    // Get a handle to an input file for the parent. 
    // This example assumes a plain text file and uses string output to verify data flow. 

/*if (argc == 1)
    ErrorExit(TEXT("Please specify an input file.\n"));

g_hInputFile = CreateFile(
    argv[1],
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,
    NULL);

if (g_hInputFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateFile"));*/

    // Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
    // Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
    // until the child process is running before writing data.



// Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process. 


ReadFromPipe();

WriteToPipe("ipconfig");

// THIS IS WHERE DEADLOCK OCCURS, FROM HERE
// PROGRAM BECOMES UNRESPONSIVE - HOW TO FIX THIS?

ReadFromPipe();



printf("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

// The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
// To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 

return 0;
}

void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for     STDIN and STDOUT.
{
   TCHAR szCmdline[] = TEXT("cmd.exe /k");
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

   // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
  // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
   siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

// Create the child process. 

bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
    "cmd.exe",     // command line 
    NULL,          // process security attributes 
    NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
    TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
    0,             // creation flags 
    NULL,          // use parent's environment 
    NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
    &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
    &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

                   // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
if (!bSuccess)
    ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
else
{
    // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
    // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
    // of the child process, for example. 

    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
}
}

void WriteToPipe(char* Command)

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the    child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
   {
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, Command, strlen(Command), &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (bSuccess == FALSE)
        printf("write fail\n");

    printf("written = %i\n", dwWritten);


//for (;;)
//{
    //bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hInputFile, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
    //if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

    //bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, Command, strlen(Command), &dwWritten, NULL);
    //if (bSuccess == FALSE)
        //printf("write fail\n");

    //printf("written = %i\n", dwWritten);
//}

// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

//if (!CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr))
    //ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle"));
}

void ReadFromPipe(void)

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{
DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

int i;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

    /*DWORD dwAvail = 0;
    if (!PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, NULL, 0, NULL, &dwAvail, NULL)) {
        // error, the child process might have ended
        break;
    }
    if (!dwAvail) {
        // no data available in the pipe
        break;
    }*/

    bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

    /*bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess) break;*/

    chBuf[dwRead] = '\0';

    printf("%i - %s\n", i, chBuf);
}

printf("done\n");
}
```

I issue the initial "cmd.exe" command which gives me the start of the command prompt. I now want to issue "ipconfig" (or any other command) to get networking info. The program deadlocks and becomes unresponsive. I can no longer read output of child process. How can I fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you create asynchronous pipe handle for self program and will be doing asynchronous work with pipe - you never got deadlock

Comment: 1) you need create only **one** pipe pair  by  `CreateNamedPipe` (with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`)+ `CreateFile`. you in code create **two** pipe pairs. 2.) bind your pipe end to IOCP by `BindIoCompletionCallback` or `CreateThreadpoolIo` 3) call just call `ReadFile` and then call `ReadFile` every time again from competion callback, when previous `ReadFile` complete without error. 4) rarelly, if you need handle read results in plain procedure, but not in callbacks, you can create fiber, in read data callback - switch to fiber, and after handle data, switch back

Comment: @RbMm: the code is creating 2 pipe pairs because it is redirecting both STDIN and STDOUT.  You can't use the same pipe for both.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - you mistake. i many time write code with **one** pipe pair. and this is perfect worked. the **same** pipe handle assigned to both STDIN and STDOUT. and we can do both read and write on pipe

Comment: need create pipe pair by `CreateNamedPipe` with `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX` - The pipe will bi-directional; both server and client processes can read from and write to the pipe. i say this not theoretical but many time implement this in code

Comment: What do you mean, "make it wider"?  You do realize that the console window can be resized?

Answer (score 4):

the most power and effective solution for avoid any deadlocks - use asynchronous io. never wait for IO (read,write,ioctl) complete in place, but handle this in callbacks.

also note about use pipes for redirect output - very common errancy that we need use different handles for *STDIN* and *STDOUT* and need create 2 different pipes pair - one for *STDIN* and another for *STDOUT*. this is false. we can use **single** pipe handle for both *STDIN* and *STDOUT* (and *STDERROR*).

1. we need create server pipe handle by using [`CreateNamedPipeW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx) with
   `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX|FILE_READ_DATA|FILE_WRITE_DATA|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`
   flags. by using `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX` we create bi-directional pipe,
   as result both server and client processes can read from and write
   to the pipe. and `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` give to as asynchronous
   mode. also we not make this handle inheritable, so not need call
   `SetHandleInformation` on it
2. client handle we create by [`CreateFileW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) also with
   `FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` access - this give ability
   assign it both to *stdin* and *stdout*. because clients (like
   cmd.exe) usually assume synchronous io - we not use
   `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` here. also by using *lpSecurityAttributes* we
   just make this handle inheritable.
3. we need bind server handle to some IOCP, for callback called when io
   is ended. here we have 3 variants - use
   [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) - the most simply way or use
   [`CreateThreadpoolIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx). also we can create IOCP yourself and own
   thread pool, but for redirect child process output, this way usually
   not need.
4. after we create child process - we need close client pipe handle
   (which we duplicate to child) and just call `ReadFile` on our pipe
   handle. when this `ReadFile` complete - we need again call
   `ReadFile` from callback and so on - until we not got error from
   `ReadFile` in completion (usually `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`). so we need
   all time have active read request from pipe, until disconnect.
5. and we free call `WriteFile` at any time and any place - this never
   cause deadlock, because we use asynchronous io.
6. some time (very very rarely) if we need complex processing on read
   data(based on previous results and state) and this much more easy
   handle in plain procedure but not in callbacks, we can create fiber
   for this task ([`CreateFiber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682402(v=vs.85).aspx)) and from working thread callback,
   when read complete - first call [`ConvertThreadToFiber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682115(v=vs.85).aspx) (if we
   call this more than once for same working thread - will be error
   `ERROR_ALREADY_FIBER` on second and next calls, but this is ok. but
   all this work begin from vista only. on xp error here). remember
   current fiber, to where need retirn ([`GetCurrentFiber()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683178(v=vs.85).aspx)) and
   call [`SwitchToFiber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686350(v=vs.85).aspx) (with our dedicated for read fiber)- where
   we can handle read result and after this return back by call
   [`SwitchToFiber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686350(v=vs.85).aspx) (with fiber for worked thread). but all this
   really can be need in in very rare and specific scenarios. usually
   handle all is callbacks with state in object related to pipe handle - more than enough.

simply example with cmd

```
#define _XP_SUPPORT_

struct IO_COUNT 
{
    HANDLE _hFile;
    HANDLE _hEvent;
    LONG _dwIoCount;

    IO_COUNT()
    {
        _dwIoCount = 1;
        _hEvent = 0;
    }

    ~IO_COUNT()
    {
        if (_hEvent)
        {
            CloseHandle(_hEvent);
        }
    }

    ULONG Create(HANDLE hFile);

    void BeginIo()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwIoCount);
    }

    void EndIo()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwIoCount))
        {
            SetEvent(_hEvent);
        }
    }

    void Wait()
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(_hEvent, INFINITE);
    }
};


struct U_IRP : OVERLAPPED 
{
    enum { read, write };

    IO_COUNT* _pIoObject;
    ULONG _code;
    LONG _dwRef;
    char _buffer[256];

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this;
    }

    U_IRP(IO_COUNT* pIoObject) : _pIoObject(pIoObject)
    {
        _dwRef = 1;
        pIoObject->BeginIo();
        RtlZeroMemory(static_cast<OVERLAPPED*>(this), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
    }

    ~U_IRP()
    {
        _pIoObject->EndIo();
    }

    ULONG CheckIoResult(BOOL fOk)
    {
        if (fOk)
        {
#ifndef _XP_SUPPORT_
            OnIoComplete(NOERROR, InternalHigh);
#endif
            return NOERROR;
        }

        ULONG dwErrorCode = GetLastError();

        if (dwErrorCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            OnIoComplete(dwErrorCode, 0);
        }

        return dwErrorCode;
    }

    ULONG Read()
    {
        _code = read;

        AddRef();

        return CheckIoResult(ReadFile(_pIoObject->_hFile, _buffer, sizeof(_buffer), 0, this));
    }

    ULONG Write(const void* pvBuffer, ULONG cbBuffer)
    {
        _code = write;

        AddRef();

        return CheckIoResult(WriteFile(_pIoObject->_hFile, pvBuffer, cbBuffer, 0, this));
    }

    VOID OnIoComplete(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
    {
        switch (_code)
        {
        case read:
            if (dwErrorCode == NOERROR)
            {
                if (dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
                {
                    if (int cchWideChar = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP, 0, _buffer, (ULONG)dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, 0, 0))
                    {
                        PWSTR wz = (PWSTR)alloca(cchWideChar * sizeof(WCHAR));

                        if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP, 0, _buffer, (ULONG)dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, wz, cchWideChar))
                        {
                            if (int cbMultiByte = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wz, cchWideChar, 0, 0, 0, 0))
                            {
                                PSTR sz = (PSTR)alloca(cbMultiByte);

                                if (WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wz, cchWideChar, sz, cbMultiByte, 0, 0))
                                {
                                    DbgPrint("%.*s", cbMultiByte, sz);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Read();
            }
            break;
        case write:
            break;
        default:
            __debugbreak();
        }

        Release();

        if (dwErrorCode)
        {
            DbgPrint("[%u]: error=%u\n", _code, dwErrorCode);
        }
    }

    static VOID WINAPI _OnIoComplete(
        DWORD dwErrorCode,
        DWORD_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
        )
    {
        static_cast<U_IRP*>(lpOverlapped)->OnIoComplete(RtlNtStatusToDosError(dwErrorCode), dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }
};

ULONG IO_COUNT::Create(HANDLE hFile)
{
    _hFile = hFile;
    // error in declaration LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE : 
    // second parameter must be DWORD_PTR but not DWORD
    return BindIoCompletionCallback(hFile, (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)U_IRP::_OnIoComplete, 0) && 
#ifndef _XP_SUPPORT_
        SetFileCompletionNotificationModes(hFile, FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS) &&
#endif
        (_hEvent = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0)) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

void ChildTest()
{
    static const WCHAR name[] = L"\\\\?\\pipe\\somename";

    HANDLE hFile = CreateNamedPipeW(name, 
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX|FILE_READ_DATA|FILE_WRITE_DATA|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_READMODE_BYTE, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        IO_COUNT obj;

        if (obj.Create(hFile) == NOERROR)
        {
            BOOL fOk = FALSE;

            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), 0, TRUE };

            STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

            si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

            si.hStdError = CreateFileW(name, FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, 
                FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, &sa, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            if (si.hStdError != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                si.hStdInput = si.hStdOutput = si.hStdError;

                WCHAR ApplicationName[MAX_PATH];
                if (GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"ComSpec", ApplicationName, RTL_NUMBER_OF(ApplicationName)))
                {
                    if (CreateProcessW(ApplicationName, 0, 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                    {
                        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                        fOk = TRUE;
                    }
                }

                CloseHandle(si.hStdError);
            }

            if (fOk)
            {
                STATIC_ASTRING(help_and_exit, "help\r\nexit\r\n");

                U_IRP* p;

                if (p = new U_IRP(&obj))
                {
                    p->Read();
                    p->Release();
                }

                obj.EndIo();

                //++ simulate user commands
                static PCSTR commands[] = { "help\r\n", "ver\r\n", "dir\r\n", "exit\r\n" };
                ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(commands);
                PCSTR* psz = commands;
                do 
                {
                    if (MessageBoxW(0,0, L"force close ?", MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
                    {
                        DisconnectNamedPipe(hFile);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (p = new U_IRP(&obj))
                    {
                        PCSTR command = *psz++;
                        p->Write(command, (ULONG)strlen(command) * sizeof(CHAR));
                        p->Release();
                    }    
                } while (--n);
                //--

                obj.Wait();
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - can you tell me what compiler you're using? I'm getting many errors, STATIC_WSTRING undefined, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS undefined, and several others. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Ferdinand `STATIC_WSTRING` - this my macro, i forget show *#define* for it, bat it can be very simply changed. `#define FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS          0x00000007` defined in *wdm.h*

Comment: yes I changed that to wchar_t* name and wdm.h is not included in VS2017. Before I get too far into this, can you confirm this code works on XP - 10? Also, what is "\\\\?\\pipe\\{46728DEE-F87C-4ef8-B2F0-1B5204862FF0}" ? Why aren't we using cmd.exe?

Comment: @Ferdinand - i fix code. this variant of code not worked on xp, because i use `SetFileCompletionNotificationModes` - if want - i remove this call and bit change `CheckIoResult` - after this this will be worked on xp too

Comment: @Ferdinand - i change the code. you can use or not `#define _XP_SUPPORT_` (2 lines actually only changed by this). `"\\\\?\\pipe\\***"` - this is only unique pipe name. are you still have compiler errors ? [`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680600(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What compiler are you using? Vs2017 is giving "argument of type "STARTUPINFO *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPSTARTUPINFOW"

Comment: i use *cl.exe* - this task not in compiler, but in `UNICODE` macro. you definitely not use unicode, when i use. and in some function i direct use `W` suffix and in some no. no fix

Comment: @Ferdinand - use `STARTUPINFOW`. but this is child's errors. you need be able understand it source and handle this yourself

Comment: Thanks, you're using some little known and I think undocumented functions, I get unresolved external symbol RtlNtStatusToDos error - what lib do I have to link to to use this function?

Comment: @Ferdinand - this is documented api - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680600(v=vs.85).aspx. and you need use `ntdll.lib` or `ntdllp.lib` from wdk. if you not want do this, you can the LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress functions

Comment: @Ferdinand - i of course use `ntdll.lib`. if you not have wdk already installed and not want install it - you can separate find `ntdll.lib` or use `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll"), "RtlNtStatusToDosError");`

Comment: What functions do I use in Windows to make my pipes non blocking? For example, with your code the way it is right now, it blocks, so if I open a exe that writes nothing to stdout, it will sit there waiting forever. I need a way to make it return after X seconds. In linux you use fcntl()/select() from libc for this. There has to be a way in windows.

Comment: @Ferdinand - on xp this well work too. i update demo code on read for correct print national characters - need first convert buffer to unicode with `CP_OEMCP` and than output in unicode or convert it to ansi with `CP_ACP` (not that `CP_ACP != CP_OEMCP` and conversion will be different fot non english symbols).

Comment: @Ferdinand - and my code not blocking. i use asynchronous io

Comment: @Ferdinand - *I need a way to make it return after X seconds* - but this is very simply - you need call `DisconnectNamedPipe` after X seconds and all

Comment: @Ferdinand - also possible call `CloseHandle` on pipe handle , but for this need add rundown protection (for `_hFile`) in object - for not call `ReadFile` in callback, after it will be closed

Comment: @Ferdinand - i update code - replace `Sleep` to `MessageBoxW` - look the changes - this is example how you can force return after X seconds

Comment: @Ferdinand - really i have own class library for asynchronous IO. it match more complex, that code which i paste. but if use it and derive own objects from virtual io base classes - code of course become much more short. code which i paste here - simplified version from generic.

Comment: @Ferdinand - about *I mean more of something like select()/fcntl()* - i don't understand. for what ?? we using asynchronous io and never wait and block. when will be data - our callback will called. for what need select ?

Comment: @Ferdinand - and use classes/objects, context binding to handle, reference counting - absolute mandatory when we use asynchronous io - no another way implement this correct

Comment: yes definitely you can implement non blocking io using poll()/select() and fcntl() (or possibly ioctl() in windows), because if what you say is true then in C it is impossible to use non blocking IO which is very false.  is just c++ is more common in windows than in linx, but look for non block select() fcntl() samples in linux c and you see what i mean. is definately possible in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I know is it a bit old so you probably won't need this answer anymore. But for those who came to StackOverflow for a solution for the same problem, I faced the same problem when building a similar project and I found a solution.

Basically, **just add "\n" newline character to the end of the command**. This is needed to simulate the "ENTER" button is pressed. Otherwise, WriteFile() works but ReadFile() is still waiting because the command was never executed in child process cmd.exe hence there is nothing for ReadFile() to read, causing it to hang there.

So the modified code is (I didn't test run the following code but is just modified based on the example the original author posted):

```
void WriteToPipe(char* Command)

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
   {
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Fix for the issue
    strcat_s(command, strlen(command) + 1, "\n", 1);

    bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, Command, strlen(Command), &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (bSuccess == FALSE)
        printf("write fail\n");

    printf("written = %i\n", dwWritten);


//for (;;)
//{
    //bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hInputFile, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
    //if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

    //bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, Command, strlen(Command), &dwWritten, NULL);
    //if (bSuccess == FALSE)
        //printf("write fail\n");

    //printf("written = %i\n", dwWritten);
//}

// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

//if (!CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr))
    //ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle"));
}
```