# Cannot read output of processes launched under cmd.exe pipe

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, cmd

I hope your programming is going well.

I have a question that I hope asserts an easy answer due to my lack of knowledge.

I've used this code from this question - [CreateProcess cmd.exe read/write pipes deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611207/createprocess-cmd-exe-read-write-pipes-deadlock)

And everything works well.

The problem is when I run other commands from the cmd.exe shell that require interactivity, for example, python or powershell, I get the initial output then nothing gets written to the pipe.

So this is what my input/output looks like:

```
static PCSTR commands[] = { "powershell\r\n", "dir\r\n", "help\r\n"};
ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(commands);
PCSTR* psz = commands;
do 
{
    if (MessageBoxW(0,0, L"force close ?", MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
    {
        DisconnectNamedPipe(hFile);
        break;
    }
    if (p = new U_IRP(&obj))
    {
        PCSTR command = *psz++;
        p->Write(command, (ULONG)strlen(command) * sizeof(CHAR));
        p->Release();
    }
} while (--n)
```

When the code runs, I get the initial powershell.exe prompt as so

```
PS C:\Users>
```

But after that nothing gets written to the pipe.

The code is using CreateProcess(... "cmd.exe" ...) and I have tried changing it from "cmd.exe" to "cmd.exe /c" and "cmd.exe /k", neither of which work.

Perhaps you would know what I need to do read/write output to interpreted such as python or powershell from a CreateProcess() induced pipe? Thanks for your help!

Comment: At least show the code of U_IRP and the piece that calls CreateProcess. But better yet, read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the specific problem and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE] and [ask].

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: Both are actually relevant, and if you click the link I posted the full code is there...

Comment: The `do {...}`  misses the `while`-statement.

Comment: My deepest apologies, but again... the -full code is in the link-...

Comment: *"in the link"* and *"in the question itself"* aren't quite the same thing. There is a reason why Stack Overflow asks users to produce self-contained questions.

Comment: I'm very sorry for any troubles that posting a stackoverflow direct link that isn't going to die has caused you and the other commenter, but I've included the relevant code at hand and for purposes of ease of reading, and brevity, have excluded 100+ lines of code.

Comment: Stack Overflow questions can be deleted. While that question may still be visible to users having the [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, it will no longer be visible to everyone (like yourself). You are also not asked to copy the entire code. To the contrary, a [mcve] should be minimal, i.e. the **shortest** code necessary to illustrate the issue.

Comment: The way this question is going it'll never get an answer anyways so I doubt it even matters.

Comment: Could be a direct result of the fact, that the question isn't going anywhere. People have tried to point out, what's wrong with it, but you refuse to take that in. You have been given useful links, and still don't feel like putting any work into writing a good question.

Comment: *I get the initial powershell.exe prompt as so.. But after that nothing gets written to the pipe.* - i run this code and got full output from powershell - https://pastebin.com/Ja6RSxNx

Comment: i think you have error with log (relative big data from dir command). all worked correct (data sended to pipe) - if use next `{ "powershell\r\n", "dir\r\n", "help\r\n", "exit\r\n", "exit\r\n" };` - powershell and cmd finally exited as well - https://pastebin.com/sHFVHqk1

Comment: RbMm - thanks for your help. I'm using Win7SP1 build 6.1.7601 and after I issue "powershell\r\n", nothing gets read back. Could you please elaborate on what you mean with "you have error with log" ?

Comment: Or more specifically, after the first "powershell\r\n", the OnIoComplete() function is no longer called. It's as if the output of powershell is being redirected elsewhere.

Comment: what i paste - on win10 - now i test on win7 - yes, really got only "powershell

Windows PowerShell 
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." and all. need debug for view in what problem

Comment: problem not in my program here, but in different ways how cmd interact with powershell. say on windows 7 if you enter in cmd indow command direct - you got output to pipe. need look which handles cmd duplicate to 3-rd program and how interact with it

Comment: Yes I think your code is perfectly fine. I've seen this problem before with interactive binaries and often times you need to add some flag to force output to a certain place, for example the /k or /c flag but I tried and it didn't work. My guess is there is some powershell flag that needs to be given on the command line to force output to stdout but I can't find it...

Answer (score 1):

you exec *cmd.exe* and send command to it via pipe to exec *powershell*. then all depended from *powershell* implementation

on window7:

*powershell* use `ReadConsoleW` for got input. so it not use you named pipe - not read from it. and you can note that console window become interactive after you exec *powershell*. so *powershell* not accept what you write to pipe (it simply not read from it at all) but read user input from screen. however after you manually input some command to console and press enter - you can got pipe output - *powershell* use (mix) both - `WriteFile` and `WriteConsoleW` for output. some information output via `WriteFile` and some via `WriteConsoleW`

on windows10:

*powershell* use `ReadFile` for got input. and `WriteFile` for output. so it read you commands from pipe and write results to it. and all perfect worked. also you can note that console window is inactive in this case - you can not enter any text to it (unlike win7)

so with code all absolute ok. problem only in how 3-rd program read and write data. if it not read from your pipe - you nothing can do here

Comment: Weird, because I know of other programs that can do exactly this. Are you saying it's not possible?

Comment: @TimCollins - what is not possible ? if program use `ReadConsoleW` instead `ReadFile` - what you can do here ? of course if exist some command line switch to select `ReadConsoleW` vs `ReadFile` but i doubt in this

Comment: If an app calls `ReadConsoleW` when attached to a console, try running it with the creation flag `DETACHED_PROCESS` (i.e. don't automatically inherit or allocate a console).

Comment: If that fails, and you know this ahead of time, ensure you're attached to the same console and write to the input buffer via `WriteConsoleInput`. If it's also writing to the console screen buffer, in the simple case you can call `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer` and set it to 9999 lines all initialized to NUL, set this as the active screen temporarily, wait on the process, and read the output via `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter`. It's not that simple if you need more than 9999 lines of output, however.

Comment: @eryksun - How do I run powershell with DETACHED_PROCESS flag? I'm not calling powershell via CreateProcess(), it's getting called from the command line. Calling CreateProcess(cmd.exe, DETACHED_PROCESS) results in powershell seperating completely from the pipes, no longer gives any output, not even the first lines, and opens in it's own windows which is what I don't want... so if what you say will work please provide context in code.

Comment: @TimCollins, CMD has no feature to run a process with that flag. If you can't run PowerShell directly, then you have to use the console API. Allocate a hidden console if you're in a GUI process. Then CMD will inherit your hidden console, and you can write to the input buffer and read the screen buffer. But reading from the screen requires active polling if it's more than 9999 lines, since the console will scroll the screen buffer automatically, unlike the way writing to a pipe blocks when it's full.