# ReadFile hanging on pipe reading

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using `CreateProcess()` to run `cmd.exe` (without the physical window showing to the user) and need to process the output. I have decided to use `CreatePipe()` for this purpose.

I am currently having an issue whereby all of my output is being read and processed, but the final call to `ReadFile()` is hanging.  Searching around has told me that I need to close the write side of the pipe before reading, and that this is a solution to this problem, but I have already done this and still have the problem.

Here is my code:

```
// sw -> path to cmd.exe, ptr is the command
ok = CreateProcess(sw, ptr, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);
CloseHandle(hStdInPipeRead);
char buf[1024 + 1] = {};
DWORD dwRead = 0;
DWORD dwAvailable = 0;
DWORD testRes;
CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeWrite);
ok = ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, buf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
// String handling for initial read omitted for clarity
string temp = buf;
bool holdOff = false;

while (ok == TRUE)
{
    buf[dwRead] = '\0';
    OutputDebugStringA(buf);
    puts(buf);
    // ReadFile gets all the correct output from cmd here but it also hangs on the very last call. How to fix?
    ok = ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, buf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
    temp = buf;
    // handle and store output
    break;
}
CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeRead);
CloseHandle(hStdInPipeWrite);
```

Comment: Without `sw` and `ptr` values it is hard to deduce what `cmd` does. Your pipe is valid until `cmd` exits.

Comment: for what you create 2 pipe pair (4 handles) instead 1 pair (2 handles) ? and use asynchronous pipe end from self side

Comment: You didn't show the code that sets up the pipe or the CreateProcess parameters. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @RemyLebeau - can assume that this is in general copy-paste from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55718264/6401656

Comment: and need  understand - readfile fail (with `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`) only when **all** handles for other end will be closed. because this you need close `hStdOutPipeWrite` and it duplicated handle will be closed when *cmd* exit. so *cmd* not exit in your case

Answer (score -1):

The child process will inherit the handle of pipe if you set `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES.bInheritHandle = true`, the write handle of the pipe you closed is only the parent's, there is still a handle in child process(stdout of child), and it hasn't been closed in cihld process, `Readfile` fails and returns only when all write handles are closed or errors occur.

In addition, [Anonymous Pipe Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/anonymous-pipe-operations).

> Asynchronous (overlapped) read and write operations are not supported
>   by anonymous pipes(Create by `CreatePipe`).

So, If you still need to send command to child process to execute cmd, you should put `ReadFile` in a thread.
And if you don't need any more, terminate child process:

```
TerminateProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess,0);
WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
ok = ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, buf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
// String handling for initial read omitted for clarity
string temp = buf;
bool holdOff = false;
while (ok == TRUE)
{
    buf[dwRead] = '\0';
    OutputDebugStringA(buf);
    puts(buf);
    // ReadFile gets all the correct output from cmd here but it also hangs on the very last call. How to fix?
    ok = ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, buf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
    temp = buf;
    // handle and store output
    break;
}
CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeRead);
CloseHandle(hStdInPipeWrite);
```

Comment: *Asynchronous (overlapped) read and write operations are not supported by anonymous pipes.* - this is absolute false. pipes of course support Asynchronous mode. are pipe have name or it empty - not affect this. more correct be say that pipes created via concrete api `CreatePipe` was synchronous. `TerminateProcess` - of course wrong and not need call.

Comment: This means that you cannot use the `ReadFileEx` functions with anonymous pipes. In addition, the lpOverlapped parameter of `ReadFile` is ignored when these functions are used with anonymous pipes.

Comment: no, you mistake. this is possible create asyncronous anonymous pipes. simply need use not `CreatePipe` but another api. also you mistake when say that lpOverlapped parameter of ReadFile is ignored - it not ignored even for synchronous files. ReadFileEx also can be used of course, even for sync files

Comment: so all what you say mistake: 1. lpOverlapped parameter of ReadFile **never** ignored. for any file mode. 2 `ReadFileEx ` can be used always, even for syncronous files. 3.anonymous pipes not some special pipe type - exist only pipes and all. which name have pipe (empty name as special case) - this not affect synchronous or asynchronous io mode

Comment: about `ReadFileEx` - it can not be used only for files which is binded to iocp port, because apc proc and iocp mutually exclusive

Comment: Got it! Indeed, the description in the MSDN document is not rigorous enough. Asyncronous anonymous pipe can be create by creating such as Name pipe.

Comment: yes, near true. really before win7 anonymous pipes -  was pipes with name format `"\\Device\\NamedPipe\\Win32Pipes.%08x.%08x"`. begin from win7 exist solution how create true unnamed pipes, but need use native api here. no win32 solution

Comment: For TerminateProcess(), I guess op is simulating CMD console, and he didn't use the command like `cmd.exe -c ***` or `cmd.exe -k ***`, it may just open `cmd.exe`, then write command to the pipe. The child process did not exit any more. So if don't need, he can terminate it.

Comment: instead terminate process we need say write `exit\r\n` command to pipe. also exist one point - we not need have 2 pipe pairs (4 handles). enough only 1 pipe pair (2 handles). unfortunatelly example on msdn use 2 pair. and almost all copy-paste this bad code.

Comment: I thought about this. But `ReadFile` May get the string "exit\r\n"?