# How do I process the output of "dir"?

Tags: c, windows, redirect, readfile

I have written a program that implements a tiny shell to process commands from the user.
If the entered command is recognised as internal command, my program executes this command.

These commands are implemented as internal functions and their output is being processed by another internal function that is able to send the text to the console and / or to file for logging purposes.

If the entered command is not recognised, I try to execute the entered command as part of the windows command shell, e.g. : `cmd dir` would execute the `dir` command and the output gets printed on the console. This is done via `CreateProcess`. Until now I did not specify the members `hStdError`, `hStdOutput` and `hStdInput` of the `STARTUPINFO` parameter.

I tried to implement and adapt the example of [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

I did not use their implementation of the child process, but tried to get the output of the dir command into my application:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;



PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{
    TCHAR szCmdline[] = TEXT("cmd /c dir q:\\Sicherung\\Bilder /s");
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // Create the child process. 

    bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
        szCmdline,     // command line 
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        0,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

     // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
    if (!bSuccess)
        return; // ErrorExit(("CreateProcess"));
    else
    {
        // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
        // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
        // of the child process, for example. 

        //CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        //CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    }
}
void ReadFromPipe(void)
// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD objectstat = WAIT_TIMEOUT;
        //do
        //{
        //  objectstat = WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess, 0);
        //} while (objectstat != WAIT_OBJECT_0);
        memset(&chBuf[0], 0x00, BUFSIZE);
        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess)
            break;

        bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf,
            dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) 
            break;
        if (dwRead == 0)
            break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        return -1;// ErrorExit("StdoutRd CreatePipe");

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        return -2;// ErrorExit(("Stdout SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        return -3 ;// ErrorExit(("Stdin CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        return -4;// ErrorExit(("Stdin SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create the child process. 
    CreateChildProcess();
    ReadFromPipe();
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    return 0;
}
```

I know, that the problem has to be with ReadFile. I can not determine when all output of the dir command has been processed. Checking `dwRead` for 0 or for `BUFSIZE` does not work. `dwRead`never becomes 0, and it can happen that it is less than `BUFSIZE`, because the dir command is not fast enough.

So, how am i supposed to end processing of the pipe data?

Comment: This is clearly meant to be code for C, except for `#include <iostream>` (whose provided features are not used). which language are you actually using?

Comment: I would point out that there are more idiomatic ways of enumerating the contents of a directory in Windows, namely, [`FindFirstFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew), [`FindNextFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) and [`FindClose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findclose). You could just take note of the current directory and the fact that the user typed `dir` and process the contents that way.

Comment: You say `dwRead` never becomes 0. If that is the case, what are you getting after the `dir` command stops outputting?

Comment: The only way to know when the output is finished is to detect when the program that is generating the output is finished, i.e. it exits.

Comment: @JimRhodes: I can compare the output of my program with the output of the dir command issued on a command line itself. When my program has read all characters (or bytes) of the pipe, it simply blocks in the function ReadFile().

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I copied the code from the given link, and did not think much about eliminating unnecessary includes :-) But you are right, it should work with plain C

Comment: @GovindParmar: I know, that the dir command is not the best example to being used here, but it gives a good example on what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I tried to use WaitForSingleObject on the process handle, but it seems like the process does never exit (at least not in my example here). I suppose, when I close the pipe, the process would exit. But closing the pipe before all data have arrrived is not an option. And I cant know when all data has arrived.

Comment: In order to make the `ReadFile` call non-blocking, you will have to use overlapped I/O. That is, the handle needs to be opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED. I don't think `CreatePipe` will let you do that but `CreateNamedPipe` will.

Comment: @JimRhodes: `CreatePipe` can not be used asynchronously, thats right. I tried to use a Named pipe, but it seems like the pipe waits for the other end to connect (`GetLastError` returns 536, 0x218)...

Comment: @WolfgangRoth yes. You can either 1) `CreateNamedPipe()` a listening pipe with a unique name, then `CreateFile()` a connecting pipe to it; 2) `NtOpenFile()` to create an unnamed pipe and `ZwCreateNamedPipeFile()` to connect to it. Either way will give you the two pipe handles you need for `CreateProcess()`. See [Overlapped I/O on anonymous pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: please see my answer to the question...

Comment: @WolfgangRoth I see no answer from you. I was replying to your "*it seems like the pipe waits for the other end to connect*" comment. If you use `CreateNamedPipe()` then you need to use `CreateFile()` as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: try now,  it took me a while to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after i searched some different terms in google, I came up with this link to stackoverflow ;) :
[How to read output from cmd.exe using CreateProcess() and CreatePipe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969730/how-to-read-output-from-cmd-exe-using-createprocess-and-createpipe)

Ian Boyd wrote there :

> Once you've launched your child process: be sure to close those ends of the pipe you no longer need.
>
> ```
> result = CreateProcess(...);
>
>
>
> //CreateProcess demands that we close these two populated handles when we're done with them. We're done with them.
>
> CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
>
> CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
>
>
>
> /*
>
>    We've given the console app the writable end of the pipe during CreateProcess; we don't need it anymore.
>
>    We do keep the handle for the *readable* end of the pipe; as we still need to read from it.
>
>    The other reason to close the writable-end handle now is so that there's only one out-standing reference to the writeable end: held by the console app.
>
>    When the app closes, it will close the pipe, and ReadFile will return code 109 (The pipe has been ended).
>
>    That's how we'll know the console app is done. (no need to wait on process handles with buggy infinite waits)
>
> */
>
> CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
>
> g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = 0;
>
> CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);
>
> g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = 0;
> ```
>
> The common problem with most solutions is that people try to wait on a process handle. There are many problems with this; the main one being that if you wait for the child the terminate, the child will never be able to terminate.

After closing the unneeded handles `ReadFile` works as expected.